# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/5) on Science Fiction & Fantasy has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: TheLethalCarrot]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4811493372592128).

Answer (score 28):

Thanks to everyone who voted for me and also for the congratulatory messages. Also well done to the other candidates, it was a good field and the tightness of the main group showed that!

I look forward to the job and hopefully I’m up to the task of handling the void of flags I’ve left behind. For now though it’s party time according to Stella:

[image: Stella in a party hat surrounded by balloons]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 14):

**Congratulations!**

Let me be first to say I fully support our new moderator and wish him the best in his new role on the site. I know he will be a wonderful addition to the team!

Thank you to all those that voted for me and maybe I can have better luck in the  future.

Comment: You also would have been great for the role! Thanks for running :)

Answer (score 13):

**Congratulations TLC!** Welcome to the madhouse ;-)

Commiserations to all the other nominees. It was a *very* strong field, and very difficult to choose a "best" candidate. I'm not surprised at the result, but we had so many excellent people in this election. Thanks to all of you for everything you have done and continue to do for the site, and (maybe) better luck next time!

As well as having an extra pair of hands to handle flags, I think the number of flags we get per time-period will now decrease quite a bit ...

Comment: Big brain move... I volunteer to create flag worthy content for you to handle :-P

Answer (score 10):

**Congratulations TLC!**

I'm confident you'll do an excellent job, seeing the quality of your contributions.

---

To those who encouraged me to run, and those who voted for me, thank you for the confidence.

Comment: You've run a few times and that shows your enthusiasm and care for this community. Thanks for running!

Answer (score 9):

Congratulations! I think that no one has done more with the user moderation system than TheLethalCarrot, so this is a well-deserved position.

I wish them luck, and I know they will continue to contribute to the site, and will be able to take their contributions to the next level.

Answer (score 7):

Time for some <s>Tender Loving Care</s> The Lethal Carrot!

Congrats my man! We know we're in good hands :)

Answer (score 4):

You've been an excellent contributor and I was surprised that you weren't a moderator.  When I saw that there was an election, I voted for you.  Congratulations and welcome to the moderation team!